# como "cachear" css concatenado via GET

Tags: php, css, cache, concatenação-de-string

Estou fazendo uma concatenação de arquivos css onde os nomes dos arquivos são passados por parâmetros na url para o arquivo css.php, a minha dúvida é se de alguma forma é possível "cachear" os arquivos requisitados como no exemplo abaixo:

**HOME**

```html
if(is_home()) {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.php?files=common,home">
}
```

**SERVIÇOS**

```html
if(is_page('servicos')) {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.php?files=common,servicos">
}
```

**Código do css.php**

```html
<?php

if (empty($_GET['files']))
    die();

$files = explode(",", $_GET['files']);
$directoryOfCss = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\frederico\css\\';
$cssContent = "";

foreach($files as $oneFile) {
  if (file_exists($directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css")) {
      $cssContent .= file_get_contents($directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css");
  }
}
header("Content-Type: text/css;X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff;");
echo $cssContent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode armazenar o resultado da concatenação em um novo arquivo CSS e acessar ele durante um determinado período até o cache expirar.

```
<?php

if (empty($_GET['files']))
    die();

// Configurações
$cacheExpirationInSeconds = 60;
$directoryOfCss = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\frederico\css\\';
$cacheFile = $directoryOfCss.'cache-'.str_replace(',', '-', $_GET['files']).'.css';

// Verifica se o arquivo cache existe e se ainda é válido
if (file_exists($cacheFile) && (filemtime($cacheFile) > time() - $cacheExpirationInSeconds)) {

    // Lê o arquivo cacheado
    $cssContent = file_get_contents($cacheFile);
} else {

    // Concatena os arquivos
    $cssContent = '';
    $files = explode(',', $_GET['files']);
    foreach ($files as $oneFile) {
        if (file_exists($directoryOfCss.$oneFile.'.css')) {
            $cssContent .= file_get_contents($directoryOfCss.$oneFile.'.css');
        }
    }

    // Cria o cache
    $cssContent .= '/*Gerado em '.date('d/m/Y H:i:s').'*/';
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, $cssContent);
}

header('Content-Type: text/css;X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff;');
echo $cssContent;
```

Uma vantagem dessa abordagem é que você consegue excluir o arquivo cacheado via programação ou manualmente e evitar problemas com cache desatualizado no navegador de seus clientes.

Outra solução para o seu caso é cachear na memória o resultado da concatenação através de algum módulo do PHP. [No site "PHP: Do Jeito Certo" existe uma explicação mais detalhada](http://br.phptherightway.com/#cache_de_objetos). Abaixo um exemplo de como ficaria usando Memcache.

```
<?php

if (empty($_GET['files']))
    die();

$directoryOfCss = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\frederico\css\\';

// Conecta ao Memcache
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);

// Monta um identificador para o cache
$key = str_replace(',', '-', $_GET['files']);

// Busca o cache
$cssContent = $memcache->get($key);

// Se não existir o cache, é retornardo o dado original e esse dado é armazenado em cache para as próximas solicitações
if (!$cssContent) {

    // Concatena os arquivos
    $cssContent = '';
    $files = explode(',', $_GET['files']);
    foreach ($files as $oneFile) {
        if (file_exists($directoryOfCss.$oneFile.'.css')) {
            $cssContent .= file_get_contents($directoryOfCss.$oneFile.'.css');
        }
    }

    // Armazena em cache
    $expireInSeconds = 300;
    $memcache->set($key, $cssContent, false, $expireInSeconds);
}

// Exibe o resultado
echo $cssContent;

// E caso você queira excluir dinamicamente o cache basta executar
$memcache->delete($key);
```

No Xampp, pelo menos a versão que eu utilizo, não contém o Memcache por padrão, você teria que instalar ele para esse código funcionar.

Comment: [**Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/99718)

Comment: Para o caso dele a melhor resposta é apontar as duas principais alternativas de cacheamento para ele verificar qual delas é possível seguir. Não adianta eu postar um código usando Memcache sendo que o servidor dele não tem isso habilitado.

Comment: tem como dar um exemplo prático de como fazer o cache na memória?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta com um exemplo de código usando Memcache.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver falando de HTTP, o uso é simples:

```
$expira = 3600; //Expira em uma hora por exemplo

header("Content-Type: text/css;X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff;");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expira) . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $expira);
header('Pragma: max-age=' . $expira);

echo $cssContent;
```

Agora se esta a falar do consumo do uso do lado do servidor eu diria que o interessante seria salvar os dados disto em um documento a parte por exemplo:

```
<?php

if (empty($_GET['files']))
    die();

$expirar = 3600; //uma hora, pode ajustar
$cacheName = $_GET['files'];
$cachePath = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/frederico/' . $cacheName . '.tmp';

$files = explode(",", $cacheName);
$directoryOfCss = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/frederico/css/';

function http_cache($expires)
{
    header("Content-Type: text/css;X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff;");

    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $expires);
    header('Pragma: max-age=' . $expires);
}

if (is_file($cachePath)) {
     $lastMod = filemtime($cachePath);

     /*
       Se o tempo da ultima modificação m ais o tempo
       de expirar for maior que o tempo atual então usa
       o arquivo "temporário", caso contrário continua com o script
     */
     if ($lastMod + $expirar > time()) {
         http_cache($expirar);
         die();
     }
}

$cssContent = "";

foreach($files as $oneFile) {
  if (is_file($directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css")) {
      $cssContent .= file_get_contents($directoryOfCss . $oneFile . ".css");
  } else {
      header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
      die('Arquivo invalido');
  }
}

http_cache($expirar);

echo $cssContent;

file_put_contents($cachePath, $cssContent); //Salva no "temporario"
```